# Not able to import module

Tags: python

So first... my directory structure..

```
---script/execute.py
          |
          L---helper---foo.py
                 L-----bar.py
                 L--- __init__.py
```

Now, execute.py calls both foo and bar .py as

```
from helper.foo import some_func
```

I am trying to run this as:

```
python script/execute.py
```

But I am getting this import error

```
  from helper.foo import some_func
  Import error: No module named helper??
```

What am I missing (note that there is no init inside script folder??)?

Thanks

Comment: looks like helper is not on same level as execute

Comment: @cox: my bad.. but helper and execute are on same level

Comment: @cox: but i am executing from a level up..

Comment: try to create an (empty) __init__.py on same level with helper/execute. But should work without, too. I use to insert in sys.path the absolute path to modules (sys.path.insert(0, ...)) so I don't mess .. , ./ and so

Comment: If you run `python execute.py`, do you have the same problem?

Comment: Works for me. `execute.py` and the `helper` module are really in the same directory?

Comment: Please, provide a minimal **working** example that we can use to test what's happening. From the description you gave the code runs fine hence there's probably a flaw in your description. Either we didn't get what you wanted to say or you didn't state correctly the situation. My suggestion is to paste here the whole sequence of terminal commands to create the whole directory structure and obtain that error, so that there are no ambiguities on what's happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check out http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages

The *"too long, didn't read"* of it is that you need to have a file called `__init__.py` in your helper directory, e.g.,

```
$ touch helper/__init__.py
```

The file can also contain Python code, but in the simplest form an empty file is ok.

Comment: The directory structure at the top of the question clearly shows that `helper` already contains an `__init__.py`.